# jQuery .on click event handler for img

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to call a function on clicking an image using jQuery.

My html code is as follows:

```
<div id="fixed-navbar">
            <div class="nav-left">
                <img id="back" src="back.png">
            </div>
... (some other code)
</div>
```

to call a function on clicking of the above image i am writing script as:

```
$("#back").on('click', '.nav-left', function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                window.history.back();
});
```

why isn't this working?

PS: These div's are added dynamically

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're binding the event on `.nav-left` instead of `#back` itself.

```
$("#back").on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    window.history.back();
});
```

If your image is dynamically generated inside the `div.nav-left` element, you just need to reverse the selectors.

```
$(".nav-left").on('click', '#back', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    window.history.back();
});
```

If *all* your content is dynamic, you need to do it this way.

```
$("body").on('click', '#back', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    window.history.back();
});
```

Instead of `body`, you can specify the closest enclosing parent element that is not dynamically added to the page.

Comment: The last one is working. It was because all the content was dynamic. Actually, this is a header file which I am just adding while page load. Thanks anyways :)

Comment: One more thing, this is working only in case when I am adding it to the same html file in <script> tag. This is not working when i am adding to external js. can you help with this too?

Comment: Is your code encapsulated with [`$(document).ready()`](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/) and are you including the external `.js` file at the _end_ of the HTML document (e.g. not the `<head`> tags?). If none of these is the problem, you should open a new question.

Comment: Great.. adding it to $(document).ready() worked :) but why adding at the bottom and not in head?

Comment: You want your scripts to be loaded _after_ the document structure is loaded. You can [Google around a bit](https://www.google.rs/?ion=1&espv=2#q=why%20javascript%20at%20the%20end), no way I can explain it better (yet alone in 500 characters) than countless websites already did.